# Program to search for substring in 8086 assembly language does not work

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

Here's my code so far. For some reason I always get NOT FOUND message on running.
I have to check whether a certain substring (HELL) is present in the main string (HELLO). How do I fix my code?

```
.model small

COMPARE MACRO
LEA DI,SUBSTR
MOV CL,LENSUB
CLD
REPE CMPSB
JZ FOUND
ENDM

.data
STR DB "HELLO"
LENSTR DB $-STR
SUBSTR DB "HELL"
LENSUB DB $-SUBSTR
MSG1 DB "FOUND$"
MSG2 DB "NOT FOUND$"

.code
MOV AX,@Data
MOV DS,AX
MOV CL,LENSTR
LEA SI,STR
UP:
PUSH SI
PUSH CX
COMPARE
POP CX
POP SI
INC SI
LOOP UP

LEA DX,MSG2
UP1:
MOV AH,09H
INT 21H
JMP LAST

FOUND:
LEA DX,MSG1
JMP UP1

LAST:
MOV AH,4CH
INT 21H
END
```

Comment: I'm sure and IDE such as emu8086 has a debugger. Have you given it a try?

Comment: That's quite a pity. It is very intuitive, though - Just hit the button to single step and watch the program state on the left. We require you to be able to debug by yourself.

Comment: Programming in assembly is 20% writing ASM source, and 80% spending in debugger (at least in first 3-5 years, until you get from "novice" to "intermediate" ... and after another couple of years you may get to "slightly advanced", then you may eventually write some asm code which will work on first try (but you will have to still debug it to verify it's not accident) ... pity you will get to "master" level in assembly when the technology is 20y obsolete, and 10y dead completely). So ask them to teach you rather 4/5 of the stuff than 1/5 of it.

Comment: BTW, why `COMPARE` is a macro? You don't even use it twice, and it breaks reading the loop upon analysis, so it's more difficult to figure out what is happening. I suggest you to avoid macros at all costs (where single usage, just write the code where it is used, when multi-usage can happen, use rather ordinary `call procedure`, macro can have only performance benefit in very specific cases, which shouldn't bother you, as you are using inefficient obsolete technology anyway (8086 16b real mode). Hm, maybe macro can also allow to write the same instruction chain with diff regs, but pls don't.

Comment: I am calling the COMPARE macro multiple times in a loop , so wouldn't it reduce the time consumed for pushing and popping SI contents while keeping the memory used the same?

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstand for what MACROs are for? You will not have any benefit out of it like you use it at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your COMPARE macro code will never (?) jump to FOUND because of a few errors in your program:

1. You have setup the DS segment register but since the `REPE CMPSB` instruction also uses the ES segment register, you still need to setup that one also.

   ```
   MOV AX, @Data
   MOV DS, AX
   MOV ES, AX
   ```
2. The `REPE` prefix expects to find the repetition count in the CX register, yet you only store a count in the CL register.

   ```
   LEA DI, SUBSTR
   MOV CL, LENSUB
   MOV CH, 0
   ...
   ...
   ...
   MOV CL, LENSTR
   MOV CH, 0
   LEA SI, STR
   ```

---

Concerning the `LOOP UP` instruction!
Since a substring can only appear a limited number of times in the bigger string, you can't just loop for the total length of the bigger string. A correct count is **LENSTR-LENSUB+1**. Here you have 5-4+1 giving 2 as the correct value to store in CX.

```
HELLO

HELL            1st is correct
 ELLO           2nd is correct
  LLO?          3rd is wrong
   LO??         4th is wrong
    O???        5th is wrong
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.

I have the counter in CL and CH is 00h by default so I think unless CH is changed elsewhere it should be fine.

I made other changes as you suggested and it works properly now.

Comment: You should follow the advice and set CH = 0, so CX is always in a proper state. This is especially true in the case if you want to reuse your Macro somewhere else at a later point.

Comment: I see you've asked a next question. Do consider to upvote/accept this answer if you found it helped you. That's how we make sure this forum can keep providing help to others.